# Getting map of nearest places when current location given

Tags: php, google-maps

Is it possible to retrieve map of nearest hospitals when current location is given? I want to do it programatically
with PHP to integrate in  my website. Any method available with Google maps?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#PlaceSearchRequests

Answer (score 1):

you can find out nearest locations according to given locations as i want to see buildings on a particular distance rent or sell... show below query.

```
SELECT 
  id,
  imageURL,
  title,
  description,
  footnote,
  lat,
  lon,
  (
    (
      (
        ACOS(
          SIN((:lat1 * PI() / 180)) * SIN((lat * PI() / 180)) + COS((:lat2 * PI() / 180)) * COS((lat * PI() / 180)) * COS((:LONG - lon) * PI() / 180)
        )
      ) * 180 / PI()
    ) * 60 * 1.1515 * 1.609344 * 1000
  ) AS distance,
  iconID,
  objectID,
  transformID 
FROM
  POI_RealEstate 
WHERE  title REGEXP :search 
HAVING distance < :radius 
ORDER BY distance ASC 
LIMIT 0, 50
```